# Why are Republicans not against forcing employers to cover Viagra?

Tags: united-states, healthcare, republican-party

In my continued attempt to understand American politics, I am now writing another question that will probably spiral out of control soon. I do apologize for any mistakes in my framing of this question.

In my previous [question regarding contraception](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/66099/what-is-the-conservative-argument-against-modern-contraception), one counter-argument popped up in the comments a few times regarding Viagra. The only counter-argument that was presented is one in which it's pointed out that Viagra is also used as a medication. However, so are hormonal contraceptives.

I found an article that shows that the Republicans did ban [Medicaid and Medicare from paying for Viagra in 2005](http://edition.cnn.com/2005/POLITICS/06/24/house.viagra/index.html). However, more recent headlines show Republicans being for policies that allow companies to deny contraceptive coverage for their employees, while they do not seem to be against forcing those same companies to continue paying for Viagra. The Trump administration issued new rules to the Affordable Care Act to do just this.

Why this inconsistency?

Comment: The answer to your contraception question has the answer to this one too, I believe.
"Those on the right, view at the very least contraceptives (and sometimes, other non-essential medicine) as NOT a fundamental human right which everyone must be given access to, but as an optional luxury. If you want it, you are free to pay for it. If you can't, go without." Viagra is "non-essential medicine" and this is largerly accepted, so no need for pushing against it as it is for contraception

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza You misunderstand my question; They are NOT treating Viagra as non-essential medicine since they are not allowing employers deny Viagra coverage to their employees while they are treating contraceptives as non-essential medicine.

Comment: true my bad. I don't have enough information to answer this, let's see what pops up

Comment: Do we have any info on use rates?  Like, if viagra is prescribed much less often than contraception, it would make sense that viagra would get ignored; maybe it just isn't worth fighting over?

Comment: Please show links to prove Republicans are trying to prevent employers from denying Viagra coverage.  I did a Google search and nothing came up.  Otherwise this just sounds like an attempt to discredit a specific party.

Comment: @RWW They are not trying to prevent it. It's more that while they did remove rules regarding contraceptives, they did not touch the ones regarding Viagra. This is being construed as them being for free Viagra and against contraceptive (thus the barrage of angry comments on my other question). So, sure, my title may be misleading, the text itself is not. I'll edit the title.

Comment: consider viagra is basically the opposite of contraception, how is this contradictory?

Comment: @dandavis How are they opposites? Both are used as medication. Both allow for increased "inappropriate" sexual behavior (Republicans themselves argue that Viagra fall under this category in the above article from 2005). Sure, one is used by men and the other by women, but how else are they opposites?

Comment: Viagra causes more pregnancies, contraception fewer.

Comment: @dandavis Are you arguing for the commandment to be fruitful and multiply? The only answer that even mention it on my other question is the least liked one. If that had been the reason for this, there should also have been higher support for banning contraception, which the poll cited by the accepted answer contradicts.

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding of what is going on with the Affordable Care Act and how Republicans are responding to it.  For contraceptives, Republicans are NOT trying to stop insurance companies from providing contraception.  The issue is that they feel companies that provide insurance for their workers should not be forced to pay for non-essential procedures or medicine that conflicts with their religious beliefs.  The law does not require anybody to provide Viagra.  It just happens that most of them do. No one is forcing anyone to pay for Viagra so the Republicans have no reason to try to stop it.